# CSS using z-index doesn't place child element behind its parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a drop down menu that slides from header. 
I have a header and inside it I have some div with border-bottom 1px line and background-color. Inside this div I would like to place logo, searchbox some links and a user profile button. When this button is clicked I would like to drop down menu below this button. Unfortunately this dropdown menu appears in front of header and not slides from behind of header (obscuring the header background and bottom-border line). I have tried solution like below (it is simplified version).

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ccca;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="dropdown">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I have tried many z-index configurations and none of them seems to work. 
1. div.background with z-index 2, div.dropdown with z-index 1 or even -1
2. div.background without z-index and position, div.dropdown with z-index -1 (here dropdown was behind header but menu links stopped working and menu was also behind main content of webpage)

How can I make my div.dropdown to slide from behind the header bar with background and border bottom line? Isn't it possible to have this div.dropdown inside header div tree as the descendant element.

Answer (score 2):

z-index is based on elements at the same level in the DOM, in other words, elements with the same parent.

Since your `class="dropdown"` element is a child of the `class="background"` element it can never be below its parent.

Comment: child with negative z-index can only go under parent if the parent has non-auto/static z-index

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a negative z-index; however, it doesn't work with a parent element that has a non-auto z-index.  Set the `.background` element to have a `z-index:auto` (or just take it off.  `auto` is the default).  It's OK (and recommended imo) to have an ancestor element with a positive z-index to avoid your negative z-indexed element dropping below the `<html>` or `<body>` elements.  In this case, you do (`header` has a z-index of 5), so it's fine.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
header { 
 position:relative; 
 z-index:5; 
 
}
.dropdown { 
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}
.background { 
 position: absolute;
 background-color:#ccca; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header> 
 <div class="background">
  <div class="dropdown">
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Child elements cannot be displayed under their parent. Make the two divs seperate elements like this.

```css
header { 
 position:relative; 
 z-index:5; 
}
.dropdown { 
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.background { 
 position: absolute;
 background-color:#ccca; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header> 
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to add { display:block } to my header (angular 2 component) in order to <a href=""></a> links start working again when div.dropdown has z-index equal -1